# Batchwise Variance Inflation Factor Calculation for Feature Selection

Tags: regression, interpretation, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I am currently working on a research project that involves interpretation of coefficients from a fitted Cox Proportional Hazards model. Unfortunately, the features within my model exhibit high multicollinearity. My understanding is that multicollinearity affecting input features does not affect the 'accuracy' of any given regression technique, but significantly impacts the interpretability of a model.

The recommended approach to reducing multicollinearity in a large dataset is to calculate the Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) for each feature and then to eliminate the feature with the highest VIF above a given threshold (classically a VIF threshold of 5 or 10). This process is then repeated until no remaining features have a VIF higher than the threshold. Unfortunately, VIF calculation is a very resource-intensive task, and to calculate the VIF of all 31,867 features, then eliminate one and then repeat the process again for the remaining 31,866 (and so on) is not feasible given my current hardware.

I had conceptualised an approach that involved breaking down the overall dataset into multiple smaller datasets (each containing the values for k features), and running the incremental VIF filtering process on each of these smaller datasets. Once each smaller dataset no longer had any features with a VIF above the threshold, pairs of these smaller datasets would be combined and the VIF filtering procedure repeated. This would then repeat until only a single dataset remained. The core assumption behind this approach was that the VIF of a given feature would either remain constant or increase when considering an additional feature. Given this assumption, if a given feature was found to have a VIF larger than some threshold when considered relative to 19 other features, this VIF was 'guaranteed' to be just as large (if not larger) when considering all 31,867 features in the original dataset.

Upon implementing this 'batchwise' approach, I found that modifying the number of features each initial smaller dataset contained produced a change in the features that were included in the final resulting dataset. Furthermore, a dataset produced with a higher VIF threshold did not include all the features in a dataset produced when considering a smaller VIF threshold. If the number of features per mini-dataset and VIF threshold were held constant, however, identical output datasets were produced.

Is there a fundamental issue with my batchwise approach or core assumption? What are some alternative methods I could try in order to deal with the multicollinearity within my experimental data?